# Different behavior with MySQL SELECT UNION INTO OUTFILE for larger files vs small files

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database of 15 tables. I'm using the SQL below to create CSVs for importing into GCP BigQuery.

```
(SELECT 'anchor_text','destination_domain','destination_page','domain_id','id','possible_spam','source_page','was_domain_dead') 
UNION 
SELECT IFNULL(anchor_text, \"Null\" ) AS `anchor_text`,IFNULL(destination_domain, \"Null\" ) AS `destination_domain`,
IFNULL(destination_page, \"Null\" ) AS `destination_page`,IFNULL(domain_id, \"Null\" ) AS `domain_id`,
IFNULL(id, \"Null\" ) AS `id`,IFNULL(possible_spam, \"Null\" ) AS `possible_spam`,
IFNULL(source_page, \"Null\" ) AS `source_page`,IFNULL(was_domain_dead, \"Null\" ) AS `was_domain_dead` 
FROM 
anchor_texts_for_domain INTO OUTFILE 'D:\\\\anyone\\\\anchor_texts_for_domain.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The example above is for one table. 13/15 of the tables work fine. However, two of the tables put the headers for the CSV generated by the first SELECT statement at the **end of the file instead of the beginning**. The only thing that sets these two files apart is they are several GB big (19gb and 6gb) compared to the rest of the files/tables which are relatively small.

Why would MySQL behave differently for large files in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would MySQL behave differently for large files in this instance?

Because it can.

Relational tables (and views and query results and so on) represent relations. Relations are a special form of (multi) sets. And as sets have no inherent order, so don't relations, so don't tables, etc..

That follows that, unless an explicit `ORDER BY` clause is issued, the DBMS is free to return a query result in any order it "wishes" (determined by the path the data is accessed and processed in the actual execution of the query).

So you need to use an explicit `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT <first column alias>,
       ...
       <last column alias>
       INTO OUTFILE ...
       FROM (SELECT <first header> AS <first column alias>,
                    ...
                    <last header> AS <last column alias>,
                    0 AS header_ordinal
             UNION ALL
             SELECT <first column>,
                    ...
                    <last column>,
                    1
                    FROM <table>) x
       ORDER BY header_ordinal;
```

Comment: You sir. Are an SQL...WIZZARD :-)